# How to automate python logging

Tags: python, logging

I need to add logging to a milter that I wrote a few months back.  It is occasionally rejecting some messages, but I'm not sure why.  I know how to add logging to a Python script from the HowTo, but is it necessary for me to add log output commands at every point in my script, or is there a way Python automatically handles that?

Basically, I don't know where in the script it fails and don't want to add the overhead of 60 logging lines.  I'm looking for the simplest method of doing this.

Comment: how does your milter fail? If it throws an exception you might just want to catch it and log the stacktrace of the exception (import traceback, logging.error(traceback.format_exc()). if it fails in some other way (eg. "it does something but not what I want", you'll have to debug it on the key code points where you think something could go wrong.

Comment: the milter is intercepting messages and removing attachments from them.  99% of the time, it works fine, but there is the occasional message that is reported as failing in the postfix logs.  Nothing more specific than "milter-reject".

Comment: Filter failure is also mentioned in the reject message.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no idea where it fails you could run a debugging session with input that you know causes the error, and step through the code if that is an option.

Another pretty obvious option is to log all exceptions at the entrance of your script and then drill down from there, but I honestly don't think that there is a way that will find the right places to log for you - if this would be the case that program could just as well track the bug down on itself.